# How to remove parameter’s value from a GET call

Tags: java, jquery, rest, get

I have a GET call to a document management system to get a document based on its document UniqueID. The URL looks like this: [www.url.com/getdocument?uniqueid=“**12345**”](http://www.url.com/getdocument?uniqueid=%E2%80%9C**12345**%E2%80%9D)
Since the uniqueid is visible in the users browser, users can navigate through other documents by randomly trying different uniqueids.
I’m looking to replace the value of the uniqueid with a variable that can be used as part of the URL.

I thought about storing the uniqueid value in a variable and using it in the URL. I’m just not sure how this should be done -high level design prescriptive-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good going Allen, the scenario currently you have is an open question for discussion and can have multiple solutions to implement.

You are right on the part where users can experiment with ids to get your data of users ideally he/she shouldn't access.

One way to curb this is, your ID it's not the actual id of let's say database or sort. you can use temp ids (tokens) which then internally maps to actuals ids of the system/db.

This will solve a few issues for you. And now to make sure that you hand out these tokens to authorized users you need to implement an access control layer.

As I mentioned this is an open topic for discussion I hope my answer serves you a good starting point to work upon.

Comment: I’m the service consumer btw.  I appreciate the quick response and your comment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you don't want users to randomly view documents, you need to implement a proper authorization on the backend, so that even if users try a random (but correct) unique ID, the API rejects the request with 403.

Second, if you want anyone with a valid URL to be able to access the documents without being authorized, but still don't want them to guess the unique IDs, you may want to add a new public-facing field in the DB and let them use it in the URL instead of the actual `uniqueID` value in the DB.

In any case, the changes you need to make should be done on the backend because there's no way to "hide" query parameters from the user if you want them to open it with a link on the browser, i.e. let them use a GET request.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. 
I’m consuming a service to get documents from an external application. As a service consumer, I don’t think either of the suggestions would work for me.

Comment: What's the service you're using?

Comment: Hyland onbase -get stored documents by id

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use `UUID`s.They can be used to uniquely identify a resource. They are unique universally and use 128 bits to store the information.

They look something like:

```
cc26d321-58fc-4cc1-978a-03f2bbdb2a55
```

Just add a column of type `UUID` in your document entity and use it as the unique identifier.

It will solve your problem as well because it will be difficult to guess the next uuid in comparison to the integer numbers.

Moreover, you might consider authenticating the request as well if you do not want unauthorised users to access the resources.

More details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: The document unique ids are generated by the document management system, then, it’s sent to my system, then my system stores it in the document table. And then to get the document, we get the document by the document unique id using GET call. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: When the document comes to your system, you can assign unique uuids to them before you save them to your system. 

But, adding a new column to the db will require you to update the existing data as well which might or might not be feasible.

Comment: That I may be able to do. So, are you saying to send the uuids in the request to get the document from onbase?

Comment: What I was saying is: 1. Add uuid column in your document table 2. When the document is sent from the DMS to your system, assign uuid to them and save to dB 3. Make api call with uuid 4. Fetch uuid from the GET request param, query db with uuid and get the document.

Comment: It is not 100 percent full proof. Users might still be able to guess the uuid. But ,it will be very difficult and this solution is certainly improvement over your existing approach. Atleast, until you implement authentication.

Comment: That will requires a change from the DMS side. I don’t think they are willing to make any changes. I appreciate your comments. 
Regarding authentication, how would that work in this situation? 
Can I use a POST and have the doc details inside the body of the request instead of the URL?

Comment: Technically POST will work, although POST is generally used to create a resource. But, it could be a workaround.

Comment: Authentication is to make sure that random unauthenticated users cannot access the docs via the GET api.

Comment: Got that! Thank you. 
These users are not random users -they successfully authenticate-, but we still don’t want them to guess what the uids are and access other files’ docs.